# IE Linking to local files with spaces works but! not any more sub folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, internet-explorer, hyperlink

Thought I would edit this as my original question has somewhat changed.

Originally I wanted to know how to open local folders with a space in them, I have this working now by doing this:

The link:

```
<a class='filelink' href='#' alt='file://\\\\TIT01\\Titan Power\\'>LINK</a>
```

The JS I use to open this link:

```
        $('.filelink').click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var location = $(this).attr('alt').replace("%20", / /g);
            console.log(location);
            window.location = location;
        });
```

To get it working I had to add the website as a trusted site to IE and this then allows linking to local files but you also need to accept a popup which asks if you want to allow the local site to open local links which you just say allow to.

The problem I have now is that if you add anything more on to the file link it fails to find the file so this link fails:

```
<a class='filelink' href='#' alt='file://\\\\TIT01\\Titan Torque\\Jobs\\'>LINK</a>
```

The folder is valid, the other weird thing that's happening is I get no link in the log like it will open the error message saying "Cannot find 'file://tit01/Titan%20Power/Jobs/" but I don't understand why the %20 is even in that error unless it encodes a URL for the error message.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: OK I found that modern browsers don't let you open local files, for IE I found adding a website as a trusted site will then prompt you to allow opening a local file which is a start but I still have the issue with the space.

Comment: This is driving me crazy, I have managed to get it working up to a point. I can open "file:///\\\\TIT01\\Titan Torque\\" but adding any more folders onto the end of that fail... I can't for the life of me understand why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it working.

```
<a class='filelink' onclick='javascript:window.open("file://TIT01/Titan Power/Jobs/2014/TTS14001");'>Link</a>"
```

Also other things I had to do were add the website to trusted sites which is not ideal for most people I take it.

Also the first time I clicked the link it asked if I wanted to allow Internet Explorer to open the local file.

Wow that was 2 days of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't set the path with the `alt` attribute;
2. The %20 character is normal. All browsers automatically encode spaces to %20;

Try setting the anchor like so:

```
<a class='filelink' href='file://TIT01/Titan Power/Jobs/'>LINK</a>
```

Comment: Ok this doesn't really work it opens the path \\TIT01\Titan Torque\Jobs but it just opens this in IE like a link and says "Page cannot be displayed" instead of opening windows explorer as my method was.

Comment: What happens when you open `\\TIT01\Titan Torque\Jobs` in windows explorer? The html above was tested with another share, and works as expected...

Comment: Thats what I mean the method you describe above just opens a new page with "\\TIT01\Titan Torque\Jobs" as the address but nothing happens just says "Page can not be displayed" as if its looking for a webpage. But I have it working with the answer I put up so that will do me I have literally spent the last 2 days trying to get it working.

Comment: I suspect that it doesn't work for you, because you don't have read access to the share `\\TIT01\Titan Torque\Jobs`... (i.e. when IE can't open the link for you, then it shows the error "Page can not be displayed" on the webpage. On the other hand, if the link opens successfully then IE launches Windows Explorer as expected...

Comment: If that's the case why does the answer I provide above work... your not making sense.

Comment: In your answer you're accessing `file://TIT01/Titan Torque/Jobs/2014/TTS14001` **and not** `file://TIT01/Titan Torque/Jobs/`. You may have read access to the first path, but not to the second. Try out both paths on windows explorer, and see if you can open both correctly...

Comment: Both work I tested the Jobs one before going all the way to individual folders.